# Angular translate unicode issue in Firefox

Tags: angularjs, unicode, angular-translate

I'm using [angular-translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) module in my app. It works fine in Chrome, but in Firefox any language files that include unicode character's it fails.

When I request the a json file directly via browser it will display fine, but when I look at the file through Firebug I see something like this:

```
ÿþ{�
�
�   �"�*�*�
```

I see the same in Firebug using the translate module. It seems the browser correctly renders the unicode characters but for some reason angular translate (via ajax request) does not. In Chrome it all works perfectly fine so I'm guessing in Chrome there is some pre-processing on the file that perhaps doesn't occur in Firefox before it hit's the Angular translate module.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Comment: You can ask on github https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate because that's a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have saved the .json file in the UTF-16LE encoding. This is a poor choice for use on the web because it is not ASCII-compatible. It might ‘look’ OK in a browser for ASCII characters but only because the browser will be discarding the zero bytes that Firebug is showing you as `�`. Windows misleadingly calls the UTF-16LE encoding just “Unicode” which makes it an attractive trap.

XMLHttpRequest (which presumably angular-translate will be relying upon) interprets responses as UTF-8 unless signalled otherwise. Consequently you should save your JSON files in UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: I had a similar problem when Windows7 encoded the JSON files in USC-2. angular-translate displayed Unicode characters in Chrome 36 and IE11, but not in Firefox 31. Puzzling, but when I found this response mentioning the strange ÿþ characters, I recognized them from the Firebug response. I changed the files to utf8, and all is well.